# Remove row from Gridview on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wondered if you could remove a row from the `GridView` on page load.

I am using `Linq` and after the `Grid.DataBind();`

`Grid.Rows.[0].Remove();` would be nice.

Comment: is this a typo `Grid.Rows.[0].Remove();` it should be `Grid.Rows[0].Remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DeleteRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Grid.DeleteRow(0);
```

This should delete the row after `DataBind`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it before `DataBind`
Because rows are created after you bind data in the gridview.

So you can remove gridview row as follow

```
int rowToDelete=5;
Gridview1.DeleteRow(rowToDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it! You should chose the fields of entity to show in your grid before data bindings.

For this you can convert your List of entities which is presented to GridView to the List of entitiesDto, which containts only fields which you need for your grid!